# Unable to pass values from one script to another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reference

Script `GetGPS` gets user coordinates and `GetAqiInfo` gets AQI information in users current location using weatherbit.io API. I have tested and found GetGPS script works fine (lat/long vales are correct), but when I try to pass those values to GetAqi script, it automatically puts lat: 0 long: 0. Where am I going wrong?

**GetGPS Script**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class GetGPS : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static float latitude;
    public static float longitude;

    private void Start()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        StartCoroutine(StartLocationService());
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.FineLocation))
        {
            Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.FineLocation);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator StartLocationService()
    {
        if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
        {
            Debug.Log("User has not enabled GPS");
            yield break;
        }

        Input.location.Start();
        int maxWait = 20;
        while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && 
        maxWait > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            maxWait--;
        }

        if (maxWait <= 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Timed Out");
            yield break;
        }

        if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
        {
            Debug.Log("Unable to determine device location");
            yield break;
        }

        latitude = Input.location.lastData.latitude;
        longitude = Input.location.lastData.longitude;
        yield break;
    }

}
```

**GetAqi Script**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using SimpleJSON;

public class GetAqi : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static string latitude;
    public static string longitude;
    public static string cityName;
    public static double currentAqi;

    private readonly string baseWeatherbitURL = 
    "https://api.weatherbit.io/v2.0/current/airquality?";
    private readonly string key = "*********************";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        latitude = GetGPS.latitude.ToString();
        longitude = GetGPS.longitude.ToString();
        StartCoroutine(GetAqiInfo());
    }

    private IEnumerator GetAqiInfo()
    {
        string weatherbitURL = baseWeatherbitURL + "lat=" + latitude + 
        "&lon=" + longitude + "&key=" + key;
        UnityWebRequest aqiInfoRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(weatherbitURL);

        yield return aqiInfoRequest.SendWebRequest();

        //error
        if (aqiInfoRequest.isNetworkError || aqiInfoRequest.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.LogError(aqiInfoRequest.error);
            yield break;
        }

        JSONNode aqiInfo = JSON.Parse(aqiInfoRequest.downloadHandler.text);

        cityName = aqiInfo["city_name"];
        currentAqi = aqiInfo["data"][0]["aqi"].AsInt;
        Debug.Log($"New data available: ${currentAqi}");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

As suggested, I did add `userLatitude` and `userLongitude` in `IEnumerator` instead of `void start()`, the code still returns the same.

but what I want is to get the users current location. It feels like the `GetAqi` script runs before `GetGPS` script. Is there a fix to that?

Comment: You only read the value in `Start` - you never fetch the updated values

Comment: Hey @UnholySheep thank you for your comment. I am a newbie to C# programming, can you please explain it in a little detail. Should I fetch my `userLatitude` and `userLongitude` values inside `Coroutine` ? How do I fetch the updated values?

Comment: If the values are aready 0 when your corutine is called, then the probem is not the one stated in the question because the values would be being passed properly. I think you should check that first to adress the problem proplerly.

Comment: @parthshukla yes, you have to fetch `latitude` and `longitude` inside your coroutine. Right now you are only reading the values once, when your `GetAqi` class first starts - so the class never gets the updated values

Comment: @UnholySheep built the project by shifting `latitude = GetGPS.latitude.ToString();` and `longitude = GetGPS.longitude.ToString();` from `void start` to `Coroutine`, still the same result :(

Comment: @UnholySheep @RustyBucketBay can the fact that I have put all 3 of my scripts (`GetGPS`,`GetAqi`,`UpdateAqi`) on the same camera (AR Camera) be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

`Input.location.lastData.latitude` must be 0 at the time its called, or the variable is being overwritten somewhere else before its called in the GetAqi script.
Check for more instances of the GetGPS script in your scene in case there could be any other, or check for all the the references to the static variables `latitude` and `longitude` (alt + F12 in visual studio), so that you can check if the variables might be overwritten elsewhere.

Edit: You need to remove:

```
latitude = GetGPS.latitude.ToString();
longitude = GetGPS.longitude.ToString();
```

From the `Start()`, because this can be read before the `StartLocationService` corroutine call in the GetGPS script, so at the moment they are read they are 0. You need to ensure that the values were already assigned when you read them in the GetAqi class.

Comment: I have externally set `GetGPS` to run before `GetAqi`, over that, when I try to print lat/long values using `GetGPS` script, it works totally fine. But as soon as I pass them to `GetAqi` they return 0. I checked the references, and static variables `latitude` and `longitude` are only referred thrice respectively: 1. When they are initiated 2. When they are given values and 3. In GetAqi script to pass values to `userLatitude/userLongitude`

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Should have used `Void Update ()` instead of `void Start ()`

Void Update = The script is updating the number of times of the refresh rate of the device
Void Start = The script runs only once.

Yes, I realize this was a extremely noob mistake. But thank you so much @UnholySheep and @RustyBucketBay for your valuable advice.